# jquery submit form not working

Tags: jquery

I want submit a form with jquery, but it's not working, i try to debug but found it even not going inside the submit method . can not figure out why

```
 $("#btn").click(function(){
      $('form').submit(function(event){
         alert('11');
         event.preventDefault();
         $.post("${contextPath}/announcement/addAnnoPubToPerson.action",$(this).serialize()).done(alert('done'));
        });
    });
```

also I tried

```
   $("#btn").click(function(){
      $(document).on('submit','form',function(event){
         alert('11');
         event.preventDefault();
         $.post("${contextPath}/announcement/addAnnoPubToPerson.action",$(this).serialize()).done(alert('done'));
        });
    });
```

still not working .

Comment: is there any warning or error on console

Comment: Have you checked your code by firebug ? did you get any errors ?

Comment: dont have, just skip it , that's all

Comment: Why are you binding the submit event handler in your button click? Is the button the submit button for the form, or another button that you also wish to trigger the submit with?

Comment: Can you should us the form and button HTML? You don't need to include all the inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
 $("#btn").click(function(){
   $("form").trigger('submit');
 });

  $('form').submit(function(event){
     alert('11');
     event.preventDefault();
     $.post("${contextPath}/announcement/addAnnoPubToPerson.action",$(this).serialize()).done(alert('done'));
  });
```

The above answer is useful if your `#btn` is not input type submit ,if its input type submit then only below piece of code will work:

```
$('form').submit(function(event){
     alert('11');
     event.preventDefault();
     $.post("${contextPath}/announcement/addAnnoPubToPerson.action",$(this).serialize()).done(alert('done'));
  });
```

The problem in your case is because 'click' and 'submit' are two different events of jquery, 'submit' event fires for form automatically when you press a input type submit button.

Comment: because 'click' and 'submit' are two different events of jquery... 'submit' event fires for form automatically when you press a input type submit button..if in your case in your '#btn' is of submit type then no need to write this '$("#btn").click(function(){});' just write $('form').submit(function(event) and its done

Answer (score 2):

Both your btn click handlers attach a listener to a form submit and nothing else. Clicking the button will not submit the form. If the button triggers a normal form submit, you can leave out the click handler entirely and the following should just work:

```
$('form').submit(function(event){
     alert('11');
     event.preventDefault();
     $.post("${contextPath}/announcement/addAnnoPubToPerson.action",$(this).serialize()).done(alert('done'));
  });
```

If the button does not trigger a normal form submit, then use @Exception's answer.

It might also be worthy to note, $('form').submit() will listen to all form submits, you might want to prevent submit handling on other forms by giving the intended form a class or identifier and use the following instead:

```
$('form.THEFORM').submit(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX Instead :

```
$('.success-message').hide();
$('.error-message').hide();

$('.get form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var postdata = $('.get form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'assets/submit.php',
        data: postdata,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            if(json.valid == 0) {
                $('.success-message').hide();
                $('.error-message').hide();
                $('.error-message').html(json.message);
                $('.error-message').fadeIn();
            }
            else {
                $('.error-message').hide();
                $('.success-message').hide();
                $('.get form').hide();
                $('.success-message').html(json.message);
                $('.success-message').fadeIn();
            }
        }
    });
});
```